# Changing the color of a selected row in an ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET repeater with an `ImageButton`. My `ImageButton` has an `OnCommand` event.

**My goal:** When I click the `ImageButton`, I would like the color of the selected row to change.

Here is an excerpt from my ASP.NET code. Can anyone help me?

```xml
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterID" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_refCode" runat="server"></asp:Label>
          </th>
          <th style="width: 25px"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </HeaderTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="row" runat="server">
      <td  style="width: 50px;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefCode") %>'</asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 25px;">
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Icons/edit.png"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  CommandName="Edit" ID="ImgEdit" OnCommand="Manage" runat="server">
        </asp:ImageButton>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr id="row" runat="server">
      <td  style="width: 50px;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefCode") %>' </asp:Label>
      </td>
      <td  style="width: 25px;">
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Icons/edit.png"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  CommandName="Edit" ID="ImgEdit" OnCommand="Manage" runat="server">
       </asp:ImageButton>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </AlternatingItemTemplate>
  <FooterTemplate>
  </Table>
  </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the OnItemCommand event of the Repeater instead of the LinkButton's OnCommand event. The RepeaterCommandEventArgs parameter will give you access to the whole Item instead of just the LinkButton, and you can set the background color of the table row.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterID" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_refCode" runat="server" </asp:Label>

                    </th>
                   <th style="width: 25px"></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>                                     
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="row" runat="server">
            <td  style="width: 50px;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefCode") %>' </asp:Label>                                            
            </td>                                            
            <td  style="width: 25px;">
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Icons/edit.png"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  CommandName="Edit" ID="ImgEdit" runat="server">                                                      
                </asp:ImageButton>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr id="row" runat="server">
            <td  style="width: 50px;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefCode") %>' </asp:Label>                                            
            </td>                                            
            <td  style="width: 25px;">
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="Icons/edit.png"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  CommandName="Edit" ID="ImgEdit" runat="server">                                                      
                </asp:ImageButton>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
        </Table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rpt_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Edit"))
    {
        HtmlTableRow newRow = e.Item.FindControl("row") as HtmlTableRow;
        if (newRow != null)
            newRow.BgColor = "#CCCCCC";
    }
}
```

Note that in the ItemTemplate the table row has an id so it can be found in the ItemCommand argument.

Comment: On the Repeater markup, did you put `OnItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand"` and put the event code in your code-behind?

Comment: Where do you see that it doesn't detect the event? Is this a compile or runtime error, or is the event just not firing? In your @Page directive at the top of the .aspx page do you have the AutoEventWireup attribute set to true? I'll need more info to be able to help you.

Comment: I click on LinkButton and does not do nothing. but not gives me any error.

yes, the attribute AutoEventWireup is true.

i edited the code. Please see, may be it helps. The code of rpt_ItemCommand is  the same as yours, except that ComandName is "Edit".

Comment: I've updated the code in my answer to match what's in your question. I removed the `OnCommand="Manage"` attribute on your ImageButton since you don't need the extra event handler, and I changed the `if` statement in `rpt_ItemCommand` to look for the CommandName "Edit" (the value of the CommandName attribute on your ImageButtons.) You technically don't need that check for CommandName if this is the ONLY action for which ItemCommand is used, but if you were to add other buttons to perform actions like Delete or Copy you would handle them in this same event and differentiate by CommandName.

Comment: I still have not tested its new solution for my problem, I can only tomorrow.
but I use OnCommand = "Manage" to treat other events: this method is that tract of data editing.